# How to use a package with a variable name

Tags: perl, variables, module, package

My end goal is to use an argument as the package. I can't get a simple example to work though. Is there a way to `use` a `$variable` as my package?

MyModule.pm

```
package MyModule;
use strict;
use warnings;
use parent 'Exporter'; # imports and subclasses Exporter

our $test="hello world\n";
our @EXPORT = qw($test);
```

program.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $x = 'MyModule.pm';
eval "require $x";
MyModule->import;
print "$test\n";
```

Error

```
Global symbol "$test" requires explicit package name at ./program.pl line 8.
Execution of ./program.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: I'll bet there's an error in your `require` statement. Check the value of `$@` after the `eval` call.

Comment: The canonical call to require is usually `require MyModule` or sometimes `require 'MyModule.pm'` but not `require MyModule.pm`.

Comment: Not sure if this is the specific cause of your error, but remember that you need to end your package file with `1;` on a line, by itself.

Comment: @David: the `our @EXPORT` assignment will be the return value of the package, and will always be true, so `1;` is good form but not causing a problem from being missing here.

Comment: @mob: you should have made that an answer :)

Comment: I am curious to know the underlying problem that let you to ask this question; there is quite possibly a much better way to solve it.

Comment: I have a script that needs to run on large, predefined, 2D arrays. These arrays will change occasionally. Sometimes I will want to run it on arrayA and sometimes arrayB. It is easier to maintain these arrays if they are in separate "config" files. When I run the script I want to be able to pass in the project I am working on via command line and it will instance the associated array. Is there a better/easier way?

Comment: yes, there is an easier way; skip all the importing/module stuff and just do `my $file = 'ArrayA'; my $test = do "$file.data";` where ArrayA.data contains just the array data (e.g. `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`)

Comment: see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html#do-EXPR

Comment: The only problem with that is I don't think you can have as complex of data structures.

Answer (score 1):

require has two syntaxes; one expects an unquoted package name (e.g. `require Foo::Bar;`), the other expects an expression that yields a filename (e.g. `require "Foo/Bar.pm";`).  Note that the latter still searches the library directories, and works with `/` between components even on systems that use other path separators.

Your:

```
my $x = 'MyModule.pm';
eval "require $x";
```

trying to eval the code `require MyModule.pm` is mixing up the two forms and gives an error `Bareword "pm" not allowed while "strict subs" in use` (which is caught by the eval and placed in  $@).

So either just do `my $x = 'MyModule';` (and check if eval caught an error, for robustness) or just do:

```
my $x = 'MyModule.pm';
require $x;
```

(or `eval { require $x }` if you wish to trap errors).

That still leaves you your strict error on `$test` because `$test` is not exported until runtime and the strict check is at compile time; to solve that, you need to be able to perform your require at compile time:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.014;
use warnings;

BEGIN {
    my $x = 'MyModule';
    my $filename = "$x.pm" =~ s!::!/!gr;
    require $filename;
    $x->import;
}
say $test;
```

Comment: I simplified it to `require 'MyModule.pm'` and `MyModule->import;` inside the `BEGIN` block and get error: `can't locate parent.pm... at MyModule.pm line 5` Is that the correct `use` for `exporter`?

Comment: You have an old perl that didn't come with parent, then.  You can get parent from CPAN.  But assuming you don't have an incredibly ancient perl, you can just do `use Exporter 'import';` instead of subclassing Exporter.

Comment: Thanks! I changed my Perl path to a newer version and we're in business now. Am I able to pass arguments to a `BEGIN` block? Could you edit the code example to use first argument `$_[0]`?

Comment: @Stuart, No. A BEGIN block is an indication that code should be executed as soon as it is compiled. Passing arguments to indications makes no sense.

Comment: @ikegami Aren't the arguments available at compile time?

Comment: @Stuart, The ones passed to the script? yeah.

Comment: @ikegami, so why doesn't it make sense to be able to use the arguments in a BEGIN block?

Comment: @Stuart, I didn't say that. You can use the arguments passed to the script in a BEGIN block. (You had asked about passing arguments to a BEGIN block.)

Comment: Ah, thank you for clearing up my misunderstanding! Of course I meant "use" arguments, not "pass" arguments, but did not realize the subtle difference.

Comment: yes, the arguments are available in a BEGIN block as @ARGV and the environment as %ENV